# EXTJS 5: Custom UI on tab panel doesnt work

Tags: extjs, extjs5, saas, sencha-cmd

I am using one of the standard themes of **ExtJS-5**

I've been wrestling with creating a custom `ui` for tabs on a `tabpanel`.

As soon I specify the `ui` on `tabpanel`, the tab strip stops showing up

In `saas\src\tab\Panel.scss` I put following -

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
       $ui: 'alternative',
       $ui-tab-background-color: red,
       $ui-tab-color: green
);
```

And in my `tabpanel`, I specified -

```
ui: 'alternative',
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. No errors on the build

Comment: Classic or modern?

Comment: @NikosJs in ExtJS5 there is no modern available only classic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the UI is also applied to children of the tab panel. You can see this if you investigate the generated DOM. However, there is no corresponding CSS, so the DOM nodes typically have zero height.

You need to declare your tab panel something like this:

```
{ xtype: 'tabpanel',
  ui: 'alternative',
  tabBar: { ui: 'default' },
  ...
}
```

For more on this, see https://twasink.net/2013/09/08/lessons-learnt-from-a-bug/